# Paypal IPN listener issue

Tags: paypal, listener, host, paypal-ipn

I currently have a problem with my Paypal IPN listener and have been receiving the following email from paypal each day:

"Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notifications (IPN). IPNs sent to the following URL(s) are failing:

http://www.mysales.ie/create_promo_listener.php"

I have a demo site which enables users to create ads and works perfectly (no problems with IPN), however the proper site that I am developing has this issue (It is on a different host).

I have contacted the host provider and they have said it is not an issue on their side.  I have tried php error logs but cant find any issues.  I have the exact same code on both sites so I cant understand what the problem is.

```
<?php include 'ipn_handler.class.php';


/**
* Logs IPN messages to a file.
*/
class Logging_Ipn_Handler extends IPN_Handler
{
    public function process(array $post_data)
    {
            $data = parent::process($post_data);

            if($data === FALSE)
            {
                    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
                    exit;
            }

           $random_number = $_POST['custom'];


            file_put_contents( 'logs/listenerTest.txt', "listener = " .              $random_number, FILE_APPEND);
            header("location:create_promo_creator.php?random_number=" .            $random_number);

    }
 }

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');

$handler = new Logging_Ipn_Handler();
$handler->process($_POST);
```

I have been trying to find the root of the problem for a long time but cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your $data = parent::process($post_data);
method is returning FALSE.

Do you have any logging instrumentation in your code to verify this?

The easy workaround is to return a 200 response to keep PayPal's IPN system happy, and to log the error for further review.